# load content with jquery ajax via dynamically generated buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working with the code in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wNDaG/ which dynamically generates some buttons. However, what I'd like to do is have each button also perform the function of loading some content (appending it to a div) via ajax.

Here is the code from the Fiddle:

```
$('#tabs div').first().attr('class', 'current');

$('#tabs div').each(function(i) {
    i = i + 1;

$(this).attr('id', 'tab-' + i);

    if(i !== $('#tabs div').size()) {
    $(this).append('<button class="tabPagination" rel="tab-' + (i + 1) + '">Next</button>');
}
    if(i !== 1) {
    $(this).append('<button class="tabPagination" rel="tab-' + (i - 1) +    '">Previous</button>');
    }                
});            

$('#tabs div[class!="current"]').hide();

$('.tabPagination').live('click', function() {
    $('.current').removeAttr('class');
    $('#tabs div[class!="current"]').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
});
```

As a start, the first thing I would do is add something like this to the appended button:

```
href="some-content/next-pagenum_' + (i + 1) + '"
```

It's after that where I need help in order to combine a function like the following which will append content via ajax:

```
$('.tabPagination').live('click', function(event) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content-target-div').load(url); // load the html into your chosen DOM element
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from navigating to this page  

    return false;
 });
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to do the following:

```
$.get(url, function(content) {
    $('#content-target-div').append(content);
});
```

in place of

```
$('#content-target-div').load(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Anthony. I'm a JS novice so forgive me for asking the obvious, but would that code replace just that one line or that whole function?

Comment: See above - I've answered this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".tabPagination", function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#ajaxcontent').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $.get(
            link +' #ajaxcontent', 
            function(data) {
                $("#ajaxcontent").html(data).fadeIn('fast');
            }, 
            "html"
        );
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note I'm not using .live(), [here's why](http://api.jquery.com/live/), but using .on() instead.